# Remove part of the data in a column in awk

Tags: awk, delimiter, gsub

I have columns in the files as

```
  1 11469   12272   ABCD:E1.121 +
```

And I want to have the output as

```
  1 11469   12272   ABCD:E1 +
```

I tried

```
  awk '{ sub(/./,"",$4); print }' file
```

and I am getting something like

```
 1  11469   12272   BCD:E1.121 +
```

instead of what I wanted, which is

```
 1  11469   12272   ABCD:E1 +
```

Comment: `.` is a metacharacter; it matches any character (except newline).  That's why the `A` vanished.  You need `/\.[0-9]+/` as the regex, to eliminate decimal point and digits.

Comment: I didn't quite understand , so am I suppose to execute it as awk '{ sub( /\.[0-9]+/,"",$4); print }' file  ?

Comment: Yes.  Change `/./` to the more complex expression I gave.  The notation between slashes is called a regex.

Comment: I did try but it is not making any changes that is it is outputting as it is 1 11469   12272   ABCD:E1.121 +, and changed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `.` is a metacharacter in the regex; it matches any character (except newline). That's why the `A` vanished. You need something like `/\.[0-9]+/` as the regex, to eliminate decimal point and digits that follow.

```
$ cat data
  1 11469   12272   ABCD:E1.121 +
$ awk '{ sub(/./,"",$4); print }' data             # Original script; wrong output
1 11469 12272 BCD:E1.121 +
$ awk '{ sub(/\.[0-9]+/, "", $4); print }' data    # Modified script; right output
1 11469 12272 ABCD:E1 +
$
```

Note that I've assumed you want to strip a 'fraction' — a decimal point and some digits from the end of field 4.  On the basis of the one line of sample data, that works.  If necessary, you can refine the regex to match other patterns in the data and modify them appropriately.  You could add a `$` after the plus to indicate 'decimal point and digits to end of field' so `ABCD:E1.234X` would not become `ABCD:E1X`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/E1.121 \+/,"E1 +")}1' file
1 11469   12272   ABCD:E1 +
```

Comment: a bit of explanation would be nice. What is the use of the `1` at the end of that awk script? This would do the job only for values `E1.121 \+`, what if on another line you have `E1.456 \+`?

Comment: @Thomasleveil Sometimes I misread a post but this time I can't see any  requirements for getting rid of any other figure. Just a particular sequence. And yes 1 stands for, in daily speech, to print.